# Displaying Sum Of Characters and Sum Of Words

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

This script counts the characters and words from three separate textarea inputs and echo's out the sum. My variable for the sum of characters (chars_all) is working, however the variable for the sum of words (words_all) is returning the same number.

If I return a single words variable (words1, words2, words3), it works as intended. The issue seems to be in getting the final sum.

Here's the relevant piece of code

```
setInterval(function(){

              var chars1 = $('#content_ifr').contents().find('body').text();
              var words1 = chars1.split(" ");

              var chars2 = $('#contentsection2_ifr').contents().find('body').text();
              var words2 = chars2.split(" ");

              var chars3 = $('#contentsection3_ifr').contents().find('body').text();
              var words3 = chars3.split(" ");

    var chars_all = chars1+chars2+chars3;
    var words_all = words1+words2+words3;

    $(".textarea_chars_all").text(chars_all.length);
    $(".textarea_words_all").text(words_all.length);

}, 2000)
```

Just to clarify, this code return the correct number

```
$(".textarea_words_all").text(words1.length);
```

While this code does not

```
$(".textarea_words_all").text(words_all.length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `var words_all = words1.concat(words2, words3);` because words1, words2 and words3 are all arrays.

Comment: That did the trick.. I wasn't aware .split created an array. Thank you!